# Don't update a div column in update panel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Hi I was using the updatepanel to update the current status.While updating it also load the image inside div tag everytime. So how to load update panel without load the image???

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="icon text-center" id="lbl_status_icon" >
  <div class="loader" runat="server" id="Div1" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div class="loadernull" runat="server" id="Div2" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
         <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Visible="false"/>
         </div>
 </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers >
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: What is your update panel?  What's the technology you are using?

Comment: I am using in asp

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="icon text-center" id="lbl_status_icon" >
  <div class="loader" runat="server" id="Div1" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div class="loadernull" runat="server" id="Div2" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
         <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Visible="false"/>
         </div>
 </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers >
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: Antony you have to move the image outside the updatepanel if you don't wanna update it on every postback. updatepanel will update all its content on the partial postback.

Answer (score 0):

set these attributes:

```
ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional"
```

then :

```
protected void yourbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your logics
    // ....
    upl1.Update();
}
```

Comment: its not working still my image is loading when update the panel

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
        <ContentTemplate>
     <div class="icon text-center" id="lbl_status_icon" >
  <div class="loader" runat="server" id="Div1" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
    <div class="loadernull" runat="server" id="Div2" style="height:50px;width:50px;"></div>
         <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server" Visible="false"/>
         </div>
 </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers >
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer" EventName="tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>